# Write normal text on stretched windows form image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image being displayed in a form that is being stretched to 3x its original size.
I want to write text onto the image, without that text being stretched.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

I tried (in refresh method):

```
    //On Form            //my Bitmap
    ImageDisplay.Image = IntensityBMP;
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ImageDisplay.Image);
    g.DrawString("MyText", new Font("Tahoma", 8), Brushes.White, etc);

and

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("MyText", new Font("Tahoma", 8), etc);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Both draw the text on the pre-stretched image, resulting in pixelated, too large text.

Comment: How/where is the image being stretched?  How/where is the image being rendered?

Comment: The PictureBox SizeMode is set to StretchImage. So what you are asking is part of what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw the text after the PictureBox has rendered it's image.

Either:

```
myForm.pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBoxPaintEvent;
private void PictureBoxPaintEvent(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawString("MyText", myFont, ....);
}
```

OR

Create a `PictureBox`-derived class and override `Paint`

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("MyText", new Font("Tahoma", 8), etc);
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, the OnPaint was just in the form that contains the picturebox.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I tried this, and it was exactly the same as before.

Comment: Scratch that - I had it still happening elsewhere. The text no longer shows up, from the derived class.